# Laravel setup bootstrap to select

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

this is simple select for my form and i can not set bootstrap `form-control`.

```
{{ Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'),array('class'=>'form-control','style'=>'' )) }}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing one argument for your select statement. 
The structure should be:

```
public function select($name, $list = array(), $selected = null, $options = array())
```

So in your case, you should change it to:

```
{{ Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), null, array('class'=>'form-control','style'=>'' )) }}
```

You can, instead of giving null as a third parameter, put also 'L' or 'S' to make one of those options the default choice.

You can find more information about the Form elements via the Laravel API:

[Laravel API FormBuilder - Click here](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Html.FormBuilder.html#365-403)

Comment: (+1) For being faster :)

Comment: This is a common thing - use a select in Laravel, populated by data from a database and styled with Bootstrap - yet is not in Laravel's documentation.  I love you.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to pass the selected value as the third parameter first, or null which is the default.

```
  {{ Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), null ,array('class'=>'form-control','style'=>'' )) }}
```